# Im trying to prevent the dialog box from jquery from having padding

Tags: html, css

I've tried calling the id in css and changing it with important and other options and I've come to not be able to figure out how to make it work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/6p0wmpr1/

```
div {
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 25px;
}
.dialog{
padding:0px !important;
}

<div hidden class="dialog" id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no class `.dialog` in your JSFiddle. You'll have to narrow it down or give us more information so that we don't have to dig through your JSFiddle and guess which element you're talking about.

Comment: Added some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not padding. Its "helper" divs added when you create the modal dialog. Add this to your css:

```
.ui-resizable-handle 
{
    display:none !important
}
```

If the gray box around your ok button bothers you (Because it bothers me), you can fix that with this:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset 
{
    background: white 
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! just one question. To prevent silly questions like this in the future, is looking through the developer options on firefox not helpful than? I thought i had narrowed it down because it had padding being inherited by div 25 px and fixed it when i toggled that. Is there a better way to find what is actually responsible?

Comment: What I typically do is inspect the element in question using the developer tools. In doing so, I saw that your dialog div had several divs nested inside of it. Divs that you didn't explicitly code or expect to exist. I just took a guess based on their class name that they were adding something to your main div.